# Ember js run function when user closes window

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ember.js

I have an ember application where users are stored in a MySQL database. When a user exits (ie. closes their browser window), they need to be deleted from the database. I have the following code in one of my route files:

```
  setupController: function () {
    $(window).on('beforeunload', () => {
    this.get('currentUser').delete();
    });
  },
```

In my testing this only seems to delete the user from the database maybe 70-80% of the time, and somehow it seems to be random whether it works or not. I'm guessing this is because sometimes the function isn't run in time before the browser has closed the window. How can I ensure the code to delete a user is executed every time a user exits?

Comment: FWIW this only needs to work for me in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work this way. Reason: browser interrupts any requests (even ajax) to backend when user closes window/tab. 
I suggest to implement cleanup on backend side. What you need is store last time when user performed some action and delete those who did not make any requests in some period of time (for example, if there was no requests in 1 hour, you can be pretty sure that user closed browser window). You can also perform "ping" requests from your ember app to your backend once in a while, so idle users will not be deleted.

Comment: I've made an sql query that runs every 5 seconds and deletes users in the waiting room of my app where updated_at < NOW() - interval 5 second (as a users record is updated every 2 seconds while they're waiting, unless of course they've left and then it won't be updated). Should I get rid of the beforeunload event completely?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it because it dosen't work as intended in your case.